# How to upload an array of files using HttpClient?

Tags: c#, post, file-upload, httpclient

How can I upload multiple files to this api https://support.crowdin.com/api/add-file/  using the HttpClient?
It expects a post parameter named `files` that contains an array of files.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            var files = new MultipartContent("files");

            var fileContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") { FileName = "test.locale.pot" };
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/pot");
            files.Add(fileContent);

            content.Add(files);

            content.Add(new StringContent("gettext"), "type");

            var statusResult = client.PostAsync(addUrl, content).Result;
            var statusString = statusResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
```

Unfortunately I keep getting

```
{
  "success":false,
  "error":{
    "code":4,
    "message":"No files specified in request"
  }
}
```

Eventually I want to do the same thing with RestSharp, however RestSharp and HttpClient have a completely different API.

Comment: Are you going to ask this question again and again for any http-based client you will find?

Comment: @SirRufo No I won't ask it again, the two classes have a different API and work in a different way. So the solution will definitely be different. I didn't mean to make you upset.

Comment: It is a different code, so I don't think it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple things one has to do to upload multiple files to crowdin correctly.

You need to set Content-Disposition: Name and FileName.

```
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            var fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
            var fileContent = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(fileName));
            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                Name = $"files[{fileNameOnly}]",
                FileName = fileNameOnly
            };
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/pot"); // "gettext" POT format

            content.Add(fileContent, $"files[{fileNameOnly}]");

            content.Add(new StringContent("gettext"), "type");


            var statusResult = client.PostAsync(addUrl, content).Result;
            var statusString = statusResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
```

Simply adding the file directly to the content will work fine (assuming you give it the correct name).